# Code running twice - python context manager

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to learning context manager in Python, basically, what I'm trying to do is change the stdout destination to write in a txt file, and later on, I'm returning it to the original state.

Here is the code:

```
from sys import stdout

class MudancaDeLocal:
    def __enter__ (self):
        self.old_stdout = stdout.write
        self.file = open('learning.txt','a')
        stdout.write = self.log

    def log(self,arg):
        self.file.write("testing: {}".format(arg))
    
    def __exit__(self,type,value, traceback):
        stdout.write = self.old_stdout

with MudancaDeLocal():
    print('Helloooo')
    print('Testing hihihih')
    print('WHAAAAT')
```

The expected output is:

```
testing: Helloooo
testing: Testing hihihih
testing: WHAAAAT
```

The actual output is:

```
testing: Hellooootesting: 
testing: Testing hihihihtesting: 
testing: WHAAAATtesting:
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Based on the observed behavior, it seems like `print` may be calling `stdout.write` twice - once for the message, and once for the newline.

Comment: See `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, by the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `print(x)` displays `x` **and** a new line. What you see is two calls for `stdout.write()`: one for `x` and one for `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing your context manager needs to do is modify `stdout.write` by changing `sys.stdout` itself; you don't need to make any other explicit changes, because `print` *already* calls `stdout.write`.

```
import sys

class MudancaDeLocal:
    def __enter__ (self):
        sys.stdout = open('learning.txt', 'a')
        
    def __exit__(self,type,value, traceback):
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

`sys.__stdout__` is the original value of `sys.stdout`, saved just for this kind of situation.

Comment: You don't need `log` anymore.

Comment: Indeed :) Thanks.